# Bake hi-res diffuse texture onto low-poly version problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, uv, texture-baking

[image]

Hey guys, my problem is that when I do try to bake onto the low-poly version I endup with a blotchy texture and sometimes the program just crashes and closes itself.

Does anyone know the best way of baking a diffuse texture onto a low poly version without getting blotchy and low quality results?

In the image here I have two low-poly versions of the original high-poly, one of which is 'inside' the high-poly version on the left. Maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8hYN.png

 So I basically answered my own question. I just did a quick test on using the ray distance setting and it completely worked. See image above for results and instructions.

Comment: Please write a proper answer to your question in the answers section, not in the comments. Others who have a similar issue might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
So I basically answered my own question. I just did a quick test on using the ray distance setting and it completely worked. See image above for results and instructions.

My apologies, I'm new to using this site as a member and had no idea where the 'answer question' button was located.

Comment: One more thing to mention here is cage baking. Other 3D modelling applications have the ability for automatic cage baking. A copy of the lowpoly mesh is created and inflated along the normals, which is then used as template for the ray distances and (in some cases) the directions the light rays travel. Blender is also capable of cage baking, but only if you create the cage object yourself and assign it before the baking process.